# How to add hyperlink to an image in python-docx

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I added an image using python docx. Now, I want to add a hyper-link. How to do that?

```
import io
import urllib
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()
p = document.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
url = r'http://www.example.com/a.jpg'
io_url = io.BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
r.add_picture(io_url)
#TODO: add a hyperlink 'http://mywebsite.com' to r
document.save('example.docx')
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the feature to add a hyperlink to a document has not been implemented by the `docx` library yet, but there's a workaround described in their GitHub's issue ticket.

Here's the [link](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/74#issuecomment-261169410) to the discussion & the particular snippet of code you can use to add hyperlinks. You can even give your hyperlink a `color` or make it `underlined`. I won't copy & paste the code here, full credit goes to those involved in the extensive discussion.

**Code example below (Credits to johanvandegriff on GitHub for this workaround.)**

```py
import docx

def add_hyperlink(paragraph, url, text, color, underline):
    """
    A function that places a hyperlink within a paragraph object.

    :param paragraph: The paragraph we are adding the hyperlink to.
    :param url: A string containing the required url
    :param text: The text displayed for the url
    :return: The hyperlink object
    """

    # This gets access to the document.xml.rels file and gets a new relation id value
    part = paragraph.part
    r_id = part.relate_to(url, docx.opc.constants.RELATIONSHIP_TYPE.HYPERLINK, is_external=True)

    # Create the w:hyperlink tag and add needed values
    hyperlink = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:hyperlink')
    hyperlink.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('r:id'), r_id, )

    # Create a w:r element
    new_run = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:r')

    # Create a new w:rPr element
    rPr = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:rPr')

    # Add color if it is given
    if not color is None:
      c = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:color')
      c.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('w:val'), color)
      rPr.append(c)

    # Remove underlining if it is requested
    if not underline:
      u = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:u')
      u.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('w:val'), 'none')
      rPr.append(u)

    # Join all the xml elements together add add the required text to the w:r element
    new_run.append(rPr)
    new_run.text = text
    hyperlink.append(new_run)

    paragraph._p.append(hyperlink)

    return hyperlink


document = docx.Document()
p = document.add_paragraph()

#add a hyperlink with the normal formatting (blue underline)
hyperlink = add_hyperlink(p, 'http://www.google.com', 'Google', None, True)

#add a hyperlink with a custom color and no underline
hyperlink = add_hyperlink(p, 'http://www.google.com', 'Google', 'FF8822', False)

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Comment: Please do provide the snippet here. Otherwise this becomes a link only answer. Links can be changed or go stale. Content will be fine.

Comment: You made a good point, thank you! I've added the relevant code snippet and will take note of this in my future answers on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you, NatKSS. However, the code is only adding hyperlink to text but not image

Comment: @Chan Ahh I see, the hyperlink should be attached to the image instead. That's tricky since `docx` doesn't seem to support adding hyperlink relations to a picture according to their [official docs](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document.add_picture) and their [github issue discussion](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/74#issuecomment-261169410). Even after studying some discussions online, I can't come up with a suitable solution for this. Hopefully, this answer would still be of use to anyone who's looking for a solution.

Comment: Your recommendation is useful for adding hyperlink to text

Answer (score 1):

I successfully added a hyperlink to a picture using python-docx with the code below (after examining the code snippet above on how to add a hyperlink to text). Note it uses run._inline() so no guarantees it will always work.

```
new_paragraph = doc.add_paragraph()
new_run = new_paragraph.add_run()
facebook = new_run.add_picture('facebook 24x24 UAPurple.jpg', width=Cm(0.5))
r_id = new_paragraph.part.relate_to('http://facebook.com', docx.opc.constants.RELATIONSHIP_TYPE.HYPERLINK, is_external=True)
hyperlink = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('a:hlinkClick')
hyperlink.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('r:id'), r_id, )
facebook._inline.docPr.append(hyperlink)
```